# What is the time cost for the preprocessor for each #include directive?

Tags: c++, c, include, c-preprocessor, header-files

**Background**

In [C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_header_files.htm) and [C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/header-files-cpp?view=vs-2019), header files are files that allow class definitions (as well as other entities) to be the same between files. When another file requires facilities from these header files, the [#include](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) is used in one of three ways:

```
#include <stdio.h>         // Include the contents of the standard header 
                           // 'stdio.h' (probably a file 'stdio.h').
#include <vector>          // Include the contents of the standard header 
                           // 'vector' (probably a file 'vector.h').
#include "user_defined.h"  // Include the contents of the file 'user_defined.h'.
```

In each case, the preprocessor copies text from the header file into the file where the `#include` is located. Given the universal prevalence of header files, I was curious about the time added to the copy-paste method of header file inclusion.  Hence my question...

**Question**: what is the time cost for the preprocessor to substitute in text for all `#include` directives it comes across?

Comment: The largest part of this should usually be the time needed to find (searching through the include directories) and read the file.

Comment: That would depend largely on the number of `#include` directives it comes across, no?

Comment: Well, let's just say it's the main reason as to why compiling C and C++ is a slow deal.

Comment: @DeiDei Hopefully better with C++20 modules ...

Comment: The cost is that to open the file and to close the file and not much more. Preprocessor inclusion does not work by substituting text—the compiler does not build an array in memory containing all the text (or even the preprocessor tokens, which is the level on which most preprocessing operates) and substitute parts of it. It compiles the translation unit **as if** the included file were included. Generally, this merely requires opening the file and reading from it just as if it were reading from the original file. The compiler just reads normally; it does not need to do any substitution.

Comment: Things that are going to cost time include processing all the text in the file (but that would cost time even if the text were in the original file rather than included), processing a header file repeatedly if it is included repeatedly (but compilers have some ways to manage this), and keeping track of where things are seen to provide warning/error messages and debugging information (but, as with the original file, that is already done).

Comment: @JaMiT, I want to know how the time scales as the number of `#include` directives increases.

Comment: Answers to this question will be opinion-based, since most C and C++ compilers employ various precompilation strategies or parsing strategies (a header with include guards will only be opened/read once, even if indirectly included multiple times). The time cost therefore increases for header files that are edited (or regenerated) frequently but decreases for headers that do not change regularly and are used many times. Bad programming techniques (e.g. heavy usage of universal headers that include a slew of other headers that a programmer MIGHT want to use) tend to increase compilation times.

Comment: The other factor in "time added" is the basis of comparison.   Header files include declarations and type definitions that, typically, are necessary to correctly call functions in other compilation unilts or libraries.    Avoiding using headers means the programmer must add needed declarations that the headers would otherwise supply - which, apart from being error prone, increases human effort, which has a bigger impact on productivity than the time for a compiler/preprocessor to parse header files.

Comment: @isakbob That would be more accurately described as "for **each** `#include` directive it comes across" (i.e. cost per directive), rather than "for all" (total cost). Even more accurate would be to mention scaling, since you seem to propose the hypothesis that two directives might be not necessarily twice as expensive as one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, the pre-processor is a separate independent step in compiling C code.  The raw time required to process the preprocessing instructions will vary based on compiler  and OS.  Compiler options that change the search order of processing or output the "post-preprocessor" output as a separate file will also change the time required.

You are going to be mainly bound by I/O time, because even with SSD's the processor/main memory is considerably faster than the I/O.  The I/O processing will take two forms; searching for the header(s) and reading the header file(s).  Complex macro expansions can also take time, but again because of the relative difference in I/O and main memory speed this is generally secondary to actually looking for and reading the header files.

Most compilers will let you generate the preprocessor output without fully compiling to binary and most OS's have ways to monitor or profile processes/commands.  You could uses these features to get a rough idea of the time used and how CPU/memory and I/O are used.